# missing elements from pcap?

Tags: python, packet-capture, pcap

When I check the attributes available to the module pcap, I expect to see something like

> [ ...snip...
>
> 'dltvalue', 'findalldevs',
> 'lookupdev', 'lookupnet', 'ntoa',
> 'pcapObject', 'pcapObjectPtr']

With note on pcapObject.  However, all I get when running `dir(pcap)` is

> [ ... snip... '**copyright**',
> '**doc**', '**file**', '**license**',
> '**name**', '**url**', '**version**',
> 'bpf', 'dltoff', 'ex_name',
> 'lookupdev', 'pcap', 'sys']

Noting the lack of pcapObject.  Why is this?  What could cause this?

Comment: This happened for me too--Mac OSX 10.4?

Answer (score 1):

You want [pylibpcap](http://pylibpcap.sourceforge.net/) but what you have installed is [pypcap](http://code.google.com/p/pypcap/), a different Python libpcap binding with an incompatible API.

There are three Python libpcap bindings used in the wild: pypcap ([recommended by scapy for use on Windowas](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/installation.html#windows)), pylibcap and [pcapy](http://oss.coresecurity.com/projects/pcapy.html). See [scapy/pcapdnet.py](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#oUP5XjT5oYI/scapy/arch/pcapdnet.py&q=pcapdnet.py&sa=N&cd=3&ct=rc) for a taste of their API differences. With their similar names people must have them mixed up pretty regularly ...

Answer (score 0):

You could also try

sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev